# Getting the current fired URL in any browser app

Tags: android, android-browser

I would like to get current fired URL in any  browser app.

For example I have fired **www.facebook.com** in any browser app. I want to know that which particular URL(www.facebook.com) has been fired.

```
Cursor cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(Browser.BOOKMARKS_URI,
        Browser.HISTORY_PROJECTION, null, null,
        Browser.BookmarkColumns.DATE + " DESC");
cursor.moveToNext();
String url = cursor.getString(Browser.HISTORY_PROJECTION_URL_INDEX);
cursor.close();
```

Above mentioned code used to tell me URL that has fired from Android system browser. I would like to get current fired URL in any  browser app.

Hope it make sense?

Comment: Well, for that you need to root the device but still try if there is any other way to do it.

Comment: Buddy, without rooting. :) Thanks

Comment: Did you find a way to do this? I am also trying to find out how this is done